# Querying Mongo returns empty array in Template.foo.onCreate in Meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-methods

I get this code in my Meteor project, in a `client/main.js` file

```
Template.panel.onCreated(function loginOnCreated() {
  var profile = Session.get('profile');

  this.myvar = new ReactiveVar(User.find({}).fetch());
});
```

And the result of `User.find({})` is empty. If I Query this anywhere else (including `meteor mongo`) I get an Array of users.

So I wonder if it is a problem with the fact that this code is running in client side. In this same file I get this query working in other places, but probably in the server context.

How can I populate this `ReactiveVar` with the Mongo result as soon as the Template/page is loaded?

If I do something like in `Meteor.startup()` at Server side:

```
console.log(User.find({}).count());
```

It gives me the correct number of Users. Immediately.

**@edit**

If I just add a `setTimeout` of a few seconds (it can't be jsut 1 second, it needs a longet time), it works in this very same place.

```
Template.panel.onCreated(function loginOnCreated() {
//...
setTimeout(function(){
    template.timeline.set(User.find({}).fetch());
    console.log(timeline)
  },3000);
});
```

So, anyone knows why it takes so long to allow me to do this operation? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

User.find({}).fetch() will give list of users on server side only.

You can probably write a meteor method for fetching the user list on server side and give it call using meteor.call.

In the callback function to this call you can assign the result to desired variable.

Comment: What method? Like Method.methods? how can I created a method in server-side and call if from client-side?

Comment: this link would be helpful in method call details.https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html

Comment: or simply on server.js after startup code ends you can create simple methods --